# How to convert MySQL Seb-Select to Join

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to write a SELECT in mySQL (and PHP) that will retrieve all the rows in "Images" table that were not ranked yet by a certain user.

Those are my tables:

Table: Images

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| Index     | Rank_Good| Rank_OK   | Rank_Bad | Is_Allowed |
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 201       | 2        | 9         | 28       | true       |
| 202       | 11       | 20        | 39       | false      |
| 203       | 36       | 14        | 7        | true       |
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Table2: WhoAlreadyClickedImg (has no index)

```
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| ImageIndex | UserWhoRankedIt | RankGiven |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 202        | 87              | OK        |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 202        | 93              | Bad       |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 204        | 93              | Good      |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 203        | 94              | Bad       |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

my logic:
when a user is ranking an image, I add to the "WhoAlreadyClickedImg" table a row with the id of the user who has just ranked it, and the image id (and the rank).
(This creates thousands of rows per each image in this table and its growing fast.)

Then, when a user wants to rank an image, I am looking in the "WhoAlreadyClickedImg" table to see which images were not already ranked by him and I add to the query the parameter Images.Is_Allowed from the "Images" table (so I will show him only an image that can be ranked).

first I did it with sub-select, but it turns out it calles the subselect for every row it checks and it is very very slow.

```
SELECT Images.Index 
FROM Images 
WHERE Images.Index NOT IN 
         (
            SELECT WhoAlreadyClickedImg.ImageIndex 
                 FROM WhoAlreadyClickedImg 
                 WHERE WhoAlreadyClickedImg.UserWhoRankedIt = 93
         );
AND Images.Is_Allowed = 1 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

I have no idea how to do it with JOIN (never did it and not familiar with what will be best - Left join/inner or right)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Images.Index 
FROM Images
LEFT JOIN WhoAlreadyClickedImg
  ON WhoAlreadyClickedImg.ImageIndex = Images.Index
  AND WhoAlreadyClickedImg.UserWhoRankedIt = 93
WHERE Images.Is_Allowed = 1
AND WhoAlreadyClickedImg.ImageIndex IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

That should do it. You just make a left join with that table and if there's no corresponding value on that table based on these conditions, a row will be brought back as a `NULL` and then you can check for this condition in `WHERE` clause.

Although, if your tables are properly indexed, there should be no real difference in both queries, MySQL should be smart enough to figure out the right plan.

Comment: You mean that If I add an index to the "WhoAlreadyClickedMyImg" table, EVEN IF I TOTALY IGNORE IT in my query, it will help the speed? How?!

Comment: What do you mean `You totally ignore it`?

Comment: I mean - now, as it is,, there is no Index col in the "WhoAlreadyClickedMyImg" table. (because I dont need it for the query to work). so you mean that I should create an Index col in that table even if I dont use it in my query ?

Comment: Index will be used by engine, not by you, try to add index as follows: `create index idx_WhoAlreadyClickedImg_UserWhoRankedIt_ImageIndex  on WhoAlreadyClickedImg (UserWhoRankedIt , ImageIndex );` and let me know how that works.

Comment: oh!! I didn't know you can do that! you just tout me something important! so basically those two cols are considered to be one index in some way that the mySQL engine looks and analyse them

Comment: Yes, that's basically it. MySQL then should be able to find records straight away instead is scanning whole table.